# Spring integration SFTP - dont redowload locally deleted files

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

From reading the Spring SFTP docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html) it's not entirely clear if it's possible to prevent redownloading of successfully transferred files which subsequently get removed.

The files being transferred are large and get processed by a local task, and then can be deleted.

However, Spring SFTP is picking up that they have been removed (either at runtime or restart) and redownloading them.

I am already using the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to survive restarts.

> The above discussion refers to filtering the files before retrieving
>   them. Once the files have been retrieved, an additional filter is
>   applied to the files on the file system. By default, this is
>   an`AcceptOnceFileListFilter` which, as discussed, retains state in
>   memory and does not consider the file’s modified time. Unless your
>   application removes files after processing, the adapter will
>   re-process the files on disk by default after an application restart.
>
> Also, if you configure the filter to use a
>   FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter, and the remote file timestamp
>   changes (causing it to be re-fetched), the default local filter will
>   not allow this new file to be processed.
>
> Use the local-filter attribute to configure the behavior of the local
>   file system filter. To solve these particular use cases, you can use a
>   FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter as a local filter
>   instead. This filter also stores the accepted file names and modified
>   timestamp in an instance of the`MetadataStore` strategy (Section 9.5,
>   “Metadata Store”), and will detect the change in the local file
>   modified time.

From this, where it mentions local files being removed, I don't know what I should be doing.

Here is my relevant config:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapter"
        auto-startup="true" channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:local-dir" remote-directory="files"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
        filter="compositeFilter">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="compositeFilter"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                    <constructor-arg value="*.zip" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                    <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore" />
                    <constructor-arg value="foo/bar" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question with your configuration - the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` should prevent the files being re-downloaded, unless the timestamp on the file changes.

```
F[] files = session.list(remoteDirectory);
if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
    List<F> filteredFiles = filterFiles(files);
    for (F file : filteredFiles) {
        try {
            if (file != null) {
                copyFileToLocalDirectory(
                        remoteDirectory, file, localDirectory,
                        session);
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: Gary, is that the timestamp on the remote site?

Comment: Yes; the remote and local filters are independent - if the persistent (remote) `filter` detects a file that has not already been downloaded, or the timestamp on the remote server has changed, it is downloaded, otherwise it is skipped. If you are using Redis for your metadata store, you can use `redis-cli` and `monitor` to watch the updates in real time.

Comment: That makes sense, Garry. I have updated my question with config - and double checked that files are still being redownloaded after being removed locally.

Comment: And have you looked at the data in the metadata store? Turn on DEBUG logging, if you still can't figure it out, post the log someplace like a github gist or pastebin etc (it will likely be too big for stack overflow).

Comment: The store is empty, I'm unsure why - its in /tmp/ and is writable

Comment: If your store is a `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` and the spring integration version is less than 4.1.5, the file is only updated when the application context is closed normally; it keeps the state in memory. If you are on 4.1.5 or later, the filter has a property `flushOnUpdate` which will update the file all the time. Also, putting it in `/tmp`  is not a good idea because the OS will wipe it out on a reboot. We generally recommend a more robust metadata store such as redis.